# Find all ID's for value X in multiple rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am making a video series in which people answer three questions they pick from a larger set of questions I have.

Every session is recorded and gets a video ID. 
I know how to count the number of times each question has been answered, but I also want to see in which video's each question has been answered.

I have made an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lsl2T5qHFtvg_spZRco0aoDfa-_ebslTBRm1ML2VIvY/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet number 1 are the sessions: video ID, people who answered the questions and the questions they answered.
In sheet 2 I count the number of times the questions have been answered and I would like to see the video IDs. So ideally in row 2 of sheet 2 for question A I would like to see the id's 1, 2, 4 and 6.

I have Tried using Transpose and Filter, but that only works for one column, so I'm missing data.

Does anyone know of a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **C2** cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(Sheet1!C$2:E<>"", "♠"&Sheet1!C$2:E&"♦"&Sheet1!A$2:A, ),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")), 
 "select Col2 where Col1='"&A2&"'", 0)))
```

[image: 0]